# Birational map of non-singular projective curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it true that a birational map of non-singular projective curves is an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes. See Chapter 2, Section 2 (in particular, Theorem 2.4(b)) of The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, by J. Silverman.

Comment: Or, for the geometric statement, see corollary 2.4.1 of the same chapter and section of that book.

Comment: I forgot that Silverman assumes the underlying field is perfect. This might be important because smoothness and regularity agree over a perfect field, but in general, smoothness is a stronger condition than regularity. I am certain that if you replace non-singular with smooth, then the statement is true over any field. But, if you require your curves just to be regular, then it might be the case that you have to assume the underlying field is perfect.

Comment: In fact, smoothness is not necessary. Regularity is enough. What is need to prove the statement is that the local ring of a regular curve at any point is a DVR and, of course, the properness of the curves.